# Display Description of choice column type on top

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, jquery-ui, cssregistration

I have created a list with type Choice and set Description for the same. I have set Radio Buttons as "Display Choices Using".
When i click on Add New item the Description is shown at the bottom. Is there any way we can show the description on "Top" using Jquery/Designer/CSS with out loosing the UI Format. Attached image is an example[image]

I know we can do it through infopath but i have some Java script in the Edit item.aspx page so using Infopath doesnot suite this requiremen

Comment: View source on the markup to find the selectors, you should be able to use jquery to detach it and prepend it to the container to move it above the radio options.

Comment: Eric thanks for your reply. I am just a starter in jquery can you please post with an example please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm sure there is room for improvement, but here is a working sample.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    //narrow down matching to dialog boxes only
    if(location.href.indexOf('IsDlg=1') !== -1)
        {
           $(".ms-dialog td.ms-formbody > span > table > tbody > tr:first-child > td > span.ms-RadioText").each(function(){

               //console.log('found the first option of the current choice list');

               var descriptionElement = $(this).closest('.ms-formbody').contents().filter(function(){ return this.nodeType != 1; });
               var descriptionText = $(descriptionElement).text();
               $(descriptionElement).remove();
               $(this).closest('.ms-formbody').prepend('<span>' + descriptionText + '</span>');

           });
    }
 });
```

Comment: You are Awsome :-). But it worked after removing this line from your code. (if(location.href.contains('&IsDlg=1')))

Comment: yep, that is if you are using dialogs

Comment: but what if i have more than 2 choice fields in the list ?? it is only working for 1st choice any help is really appreciated... please

Comment: it is your lucky day I guess

Comment: You are too great..... infinity thanks to your work. You made me so lucky ..... Do you have any  blog  where i can follow up you

Comment: you can find that on my profile. glad it worked

Comment: Last help what if i have field type as multiple lines of text . I tried like this but it did not work. As i said i am very poor in Jquery.
$("td.ms-formbody > span > div.ms-rtestate-field ms-rtefield").each(function(){

Comment: you are missing a dot on "ms-rtefield". as long as you know "." represents classes, "#" represents ids and ">" represents the immediate child, you should be able to find what you are looking for

Comment: Do you add this using script editor webpart or in the master page? Can you show where to insert it? Appreciate it.

Comment: @normsp there are several ways to do it, depends on your context, namely number of pages where you want it. a simple method is opening the form and adding it just before the closing of PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead, wrapped around script tags

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for [Tiago for providing the solution](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/109891/6382). So here is the code if you want to move description up for Multiple lines of text.

```
$("td.ms-formbody > span > textarea.ms-long").each(function(){


 var descriptionElement = $(this).closest('.ms-formbody').contents().filter(function(){ return this.nodeType != 1; });
  var descriptionText = $(descriptionElement).text();
   //alert(descriptionText);
 $(descriptionElement).remove();
 $(this).closest('.ms-formbody').prepend('<span>' + descriptionText + '</span>');
 $('.ms-long').css({'height':'auto','display':'block','margin-top':'10px'});
});
```

Comment: it is not very nice to throw away ones effort by selecting your own question as answer, when it doesnt even answer the question you originally asked, and kindly answered by me

Comment: You should really mark Tiago's answer as the Accepted answer, since he actually have you the solution.

Comment: Sorry first I marked your solution only. Later I marked my answer for multiple line of text. O will in mark my answer. Really sorry and don't think bad

Comment: @sandy_9866141457 Good sports Sandy! I've linked your answer to Tiagos and changed my down vote to an upvote. Thanks for participating in our Community!

Comment: This is not working in Sharepoint 2013. Any change in that? have you tried the same