# Display Description of choice column type on top in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, javascript

I have created a list with type `Choice` and set `Description` for the same. I have set `Radio Buttons` as `Display Choices Using`. 
When I click on `Add New item` the description is shown at the bottom. 
Is there any way we can show the description on "Top" using jQuery / SharePoint Designer / CSS without loosing the UI Format?
I have already achieved this in SharePoint 2010, but we recently  migrated to 2013 and it is not working. 
Here is my last post where I have posted and it is working fine .
Code in 2010

```
$("td.ms-formbody > span > table > tbody > tr:first-child > td > span.ms-RadioText").each(function(){

               console.log('found the first option of the current choice list');

               var descriptionElement = $(this).closest('.ms-formbody').contents().filter(function(){ return this.nodeType != 1; });
               var descriptionText = $(descriptionElement).text();
               $(descriptionElement).remove();
               $(this).closest('.ms-formbody').prepend('<span>' + descriptionText + '</span>');
               $('.ms-RadioText').css({'height':'auto','display':'block','margin-top':'10px'});

           });
```

[Display Description of choice column type on top](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/109829/display-description-of-choice-column-type-on-top)

When i tried the below code as suggested by **Nagarajan Muthukumar**it is appending the next level description. Screenshot below[[image: 1]]

Comment: are you using the default/out-of-box form??

Comment: Default list form

Comment: Using jquery only we can achieve this, in case, if you dont find a proper solution an alternate way is create a new form using SP Designer, this custom form will have same look as of default form, added advantage here is you can see all fields in designer (Code View), below your field you can find another control for description, just move it above your control.. Simplest way I guess

Comment: then you can set the custom form as default

Comment: No it is not possible with designer. I tried the same in 2010 where it is working fine which I have posted the link. However it is not working in 2013. This is because of some object change

Comment: Is there a way this can be applied to the DispForm.aspx view? Can you provide script to display the Description in that view?

Comment: Hi @Dave Englund , welcome to SharePoint StackExchange :) you can ask your question at https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/ask also please don't forget to take a quick tour at https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour to get informed badge!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope the below code will help you,

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(function(){
var Obj=$('td.ms-formlabel h3.ms-standardheader nobr').filter(function() { return $(this).text() === "Choice Field"; });
var desc = Obj.parent().parent().next().find("span.ms-metadata").text();
Obj.parent().parent().next().find("span.ms-metadata").hide()
Obj.parent().parent().next().prepend('<span class="ms-metadata">'+desc+'</span>');
});
</script>
```

Replace the "Choice Field" with the display name of you field in the above script.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below code, it is working for me. I have tested the code in SharePoint 2013 list,

Insert the below code in the NewForm and EditForm page of the list.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(function(){
var desc = $("td.ms-formlabel h3.ms-standardheader nobr:contains('Choice Field')").parent().parent().next().find("span.ms-metadata").text();
$("td.ms-formlabel h3.ms-standardheader nobr:contains('Choice Field')").parent().parent().next().find("span.ms-metadata").hide()
$("td.ms-formlabel h3.ms-standardheader nobr:contains('Choice Field')").parent().parent().next().prepend('<span class="ms-metadata">'+desc+'</span>');
});
</script>
```

Note: Replace the field name in the script with the display name of the field.

Comment: Is Choice test teh field name or Choice Field is the Field Name?? Also have you take internal name or static name. I tried Replacing Choice test with my internal name and it is not working..

Comment: I have edited with screen shot my choice field is of radio button...

Comment: It should be Display name of the field. Replace the text 'Choice Field' in the code with Display name of your field.

Comment: The code which i have given works for default New Form. Are you using OOTB new form or you have customized it?

Comment: No I have not customized it . I have almost around 10 choice field. I have put the code which is working fine in 2010 for all the choice fields where type is of radio button . Can you have a glance on it and help me out

Comment: Can you provide the html content of your page, only from <tr> tag in which your field is present.

Comment: I Have attached the screen shot of my <tr>tag.

Comment: I need the previous <td> where your field name 'Vendor-Invoice Accuracy' is present. Expand every inner tags from the <tr> tag and share the screen shot.

Comment: i have shared the same. Really appreciate your help

Comment: I have the same HTML format. and the code works for me. Check whether you have replaced the Choice filed display name at all the three places. Check whether you have any script error in the page. Try putting alerts in each step of the code and check where the code is breaking.

Comment: It is Working. But the Problem is if i have my form like this it is overriding the next  one.  eample. 1) choice field 2) multiple lines of text 3) choice 4) multiple lines of text so multiple lines of text description is coming in the choice field

Comment: Nagarajan Muthukumar i have added the screen shot how it is appending the next control description.